# Misophonia and autism

Tags: brain, autism, sensitivity-intolerance, soundwaves, misophonia

I would like to know, is there an area of overlap between misophonia and autism? Because I have heard autistic people are sensitive to specific sounds in absence of love and cover their ears. How different are these conditions?

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Answer (score -3):

Regrettably, there has been no diagnostics code or preliminary research done for a connection between misophonia and autism. **Instead, there are some commonalities between the two.**

**Autism or autism spectrum disorder** is a complex neural damage caused in the brain wiring of a person with remarkable signs of learning disabilities and repetitive behavior.

**Misophonia**, like autism, is in reference to the psychiatric or mental health of a person. It is a condition likely to show a number of influences without much of the evidence.

Individuals with autism often become overwhelmed by **sensory processing disorder**. Loud noises can irritate and even lead to a lack of functioning near the sounds resulting injurious for an autistic person. This certainly is a similar case to misophonia.

References:

https://misophoniainstitute.org/how-children-develop-misophonia/

https://www.misophoniainternational.com/misophonia-autism-connection/

Comment: Same with your other answers, please include references for your claims and exclude advertisements.

Comment: As Narusan pointed out, answers here require supporting references. And please do not add promotional content to your answers. It has been removed.